# Set-up/clean-up only once per feature method with 'where:' block

Tags: unit-testing, spock

Spock has `setupSpec` on the Spec class level. I would want to have something similar for a single test case level.

This might not be available in Spock, Does someone has a workaround for this.

```groovy
void "test something"() {
    setup:
    User user = createUser()

    when:
    user.setAdress(new Address(zipCode: inputZipCode, city: inputCity))

    then:
    user.address.city == inputCity
    user.address.zipCode == inputZipCode

    cleanup:
    deleteUser(user)

    where:
    inputCity | inputZipCode
    "a" |"1"
    "b" |"2"
}
```

Creating and deleting user is unnecessarily done after every iteration.

- Could it be possible to have something la- `setupSpec` for a single test instead of class-level?
- It is possible to manipulate the test cases to use class-setupSpec/CleanupSpec or even create a new test (with @Stepwise) to achieve this but I am looking for something good solution not a hack.

Comment: To me it is completely unclear what you want to achieve. If you want something done once for the whole specification (test class), use `setupSpec()`. If you want it done for each feature method, use `setup()`. If you want it done for just one method, use `setup:`. Every possible case is covered. What else do you need? You don't really want to bleed context into the next iteration of your `where:` data set. The user you create is manipulated during the iteration. It makes sense to set up and clean up your test fixture in between iterations so as to make tests independent of each other.

Comment: This is just an example, Say I want to test something entirely different which has no modification in the user object. And if this is an integration test case and creating and deleting user takes too significant time and I don't want to repeat that for everywhere block (if there are too many data-driven specs). I understand a test should be as much as possible self-contained, but I was just wondering if there is already a way to do that. The only solution I could see is to use AST transformation to have `setupSpec` and `cleanupSpec` for individual test which will not repeat for where block

Comment: The proper way would be to write a custom extension http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/extensions.html#_writing_custom_extensions. If you register the appropriate interceptors you can achieve what you want. See the builtin `RetryExtension` with `mode=FEATURE` as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is very ugly because it involves manual bookkeeping. I do not recommend you to do it like this, but anyway:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q57721328

import spock.lang.See
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class OneTimeSetupCleanupParametrisedTest extends Specification {
  @Shared User user
  @Shared int iteration

  User createUser() {
    // Set up test fixture only if iteration == 0 (or optionally, if fixture is uninitialised) 
    user ?: new User()
  }

  void deleteUser(User userInstance) {
    // Clean up counter (and test fixture, if any) only if iteration == total number of iterations
    if (++iteration == specificationContext.currentIteration.estimatedNumIterations) {
      userInstance.delete()
      user = null
      iteration = 0
    }
  }

//  @Unroll
  void "test something"() {
    setup:
    // Call initialiser helper for each iteration, relying on the fact that it will only
    // create a text fixture if none exists yet
    user = createUser()

    when:
    user.setAdress(new Address(zipCode: inputZipCode, city: inputCity))

    then:
    user.address.city == inputCity
    user.address.zipCode == inputZipCode

    cleanup:
    // Call clean-up helper for each iteration, relying on the fact that it will only
    // clean up the fixture during the last iteration
    deleteUser(user)

    where:
    inputCity | inputZipCode
    "a"       | "1"
    "b"       | "2"
  }

  static class User {
    Address address

    User() {
      println "creating user"
    }

    void setAdress(Address address) {
      this.address = address
    }

    void delete() {
      println "deleting user"
      address = null
    }
  }

  static class Address {
    String zipCode, city
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
creating user
deleting user
```

---

**Update:** The Spock manual says [about this topic](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_sharing_of_objects_between_iterations):

> #### Sharing of Objects between Iterations
>
> In order to share an object between iterations, it has to be kept in a @Shared or static field.
>
> **NOTE:** Only `@Shared` and `static` variables can be accessed from within a `where:` block.
>
> Note that such objects will also be shared with other methods. There is currently no good way to share an object just between iterations of the same method. If you consider this a problem, consider putting each method into a separate spec, all of which can be kept in the same file. This achieves better isolation at the cost of some boilerplate code.